# PGFPlot 3D opacity and appearance

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, transparency

I used MATLAB to generate some 3D figures and I would like to show two surfaces in one graphic using PGFPlots.
In order to better illustrate the surface differences, I set opacity = 0.5 for both of them.
The matlab figure perfectly shows the spots where the blue function is greater than the red one, as you can see below.
[image]

The PGFplot is a little bit different:
[image]

I have already tried matlab2tikz and it did not work very well.

What can I do to improve my **TeX code**?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={prop}{
                                                            rgb255=(1,1,255)
                                                            rgb255=(10, 10, 255)
                                                    }}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={berg}{
                                                            rgb255=(255,1,1)
                                                            rgb255=(255, 10, 10)
                                                    }}

\begin{filecontents}{TPTC.dat}
  -5.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02
  -5.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01
  -5.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
  -5.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01
  -5.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
  -5.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   2.5000000e-01
  -5.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
  -5.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   1.6666667e-01
  -5.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   3.3333333e-01
  -5.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-02
  -5.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   2.5000000e-01
  -4.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -4.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -4.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
  -4.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
  -4.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   3.3333333e-01
  -4.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   1.6666667e-01
  -4.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
  -4.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01
  -4.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-02
  -4.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   4.1666667e-01
  -4.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   4.1666667e-01
  -3.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
  -3.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   0.0000000e+00
  -3.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
  -3.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
  -3.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
  -3.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
  -3.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-02
  -3.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -3.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   2.5000000e-01
  -3.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   3.3333333e-01
  -3.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   7.5000000e-01
  -2.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   0.0000000e+00
  -2.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   8.3333333e-02
  -2.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   3.3333333e-01
  -2.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   1.6666667e-01
  -2.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -2.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   3.3333333e-01
  -2.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -2.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   4.1666667e-01
  -2.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   4.1666667e-01
  -2.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   1.0000000e+00
  -1.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -1.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   1.6666667e-01
  -1.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
  -1.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-02
  -1.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   3.3333333e-01
  -1.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   3.3333333e-01
  -1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   4.1666667e-01
  -1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   5.8333333e-01
  -1.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   1.6666667e-01
  -1.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   9.1666667e-01
  -1.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.0833333e+00
   0.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   0.0000000e+00
   0.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
   0.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   2.5000000e-01
   0.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   1.6666667e-01
   0.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   5.8333333e-01   8.3333333e-02
   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   3.3333333e-01
   0.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   5.8333333e-01
   0.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   5.8333333e-01
   0.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
   0.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   1.0833333e+00   9.1666667e-01
   0.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   7.5000000e-01   1.2500000e+00
   1.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   1.6666667e-01
   1.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
   1.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   2.5000000e-01
   1.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   2.5000000e-01
   1.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   1.6666667e-01
   1.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   6.6666667e-01
   1.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   4.1666667e-01
   1.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.0833333e+00
   1.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   5.8333333e-01   9.1666667e-01
   1.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.4166667e+00
   1.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   9.1666667e-01   9.1666667e-01
   2.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   8.3333333e-02
   2.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   2.5000000e-01
   2.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   2.5000000e-01
   2.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-02
   2.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   5.8333333e-01
   2.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   4.1666667e-01
   2.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   7.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-01
   2.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-01   7.5000000e-01
   2.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.1666667e+00
   2.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   1.2500000e+00
   2.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   7.5000000e-01   1.4166667e+00
   3.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   1.6666667e-01
   3.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   4.1666667e-01
   3.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   5.8333333e-01
   3.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   4.1666667e-01
   3.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   1.6666667e-01   2.5000000e-01
   3.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   1.0833333e+00
   3.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   9.1666667e-01
   3.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   7.5000000e-01
   3.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   5.0000000e-01   1.2500000e+00
   3.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   6.6666667e-01   1.0833333e+00
   3.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   1.4166667e+00   1.2500000e+00
   4.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.6666667e-01
   4.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   2.5000000e-01
   4.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
   4.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   4.1666667e-01
   4.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   8.3333333e-01
   4.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   9.1666667e-01
   4.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   4.1666667e-01
   4.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   4.1666667e-01   1.2500000e+00
   4.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   1.2500000e+00
   4.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   9.1666667e-01   1.5833333e+00
   4.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   1.2500000e+00   1.4166667e+00
   5.0000000e+00  -5.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   0.0000000e+00
   5.0000000e+00  -4.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   7.5000000e-01
   5.0000000e+00  -3.0000000e+00   3.3333333e-01   8.3333333e-01
   5.0000000e+00  -2.0000000e+00   8.3333333e-02   2.5000000e-01
   5.0000000e+00  -1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   6.6666667e-01
   5.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   5.8333333e-01
   5.0000000e+00   1.0000000e+00   2.5000000e-01   9.1666667e-01
   5.0000000e+00   2.0000000e+00   5.8333333e-01   1.5000000e+00
   5.0000000e+00   3.0000000e+00   1.2500000e+00   1.2500000e+00
   5.0000000e+00   4.0000000e+00   1.0833333e+00   1.4166667e+00
   5.0000000e+00   5.0000000e+00   1.0833333e+00   1.0833333e+00
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,
                                            loop,
                                            controls,
                                            %viewport=0 0 110 153,
                                            %scale = 0.9;
                                            buttonsize=3ex,
                                            buttonfg=1.0:1.0:1.0,
                                            buttonbg=0.5]{0.4} % frames por segundo
        \multiframe{4}{i=1+1}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
%3d box,
width=0.9\textwidth,
height=0.75\textwidth,
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
xtick={-2.5,0,2.5},
tick align=outside,
extra x ticks={-5,5},
        extra tick style={
            grid=none,
        },
xlabel={erro TP [\%]},
ymin=-5,
ymax=5,
ytick={-2.5,0,2.5},
extra y ticks={-5,5},
        extra tick style={
            grid=none,
        },
ylabel={erro TC [\%]},
zmin=0,
zmax=2,
ztick={0,0.5,1,1.5},
extra z ticks={2},
        extra tick style={
            grid=none,
        },
zlabel={erro relativo [\%]},
view={-15+360*(\i-1)/4}{47},
grid = major,
grid style=dashed
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
draw = black,
line width = 0.05pt,
%shader= flat corner,
colormap name=prop,
fill opacity = 0.5,
z buffer=auto,
unbounded coords=jump,
mesh/rows=11]
table[x index=0,y index=1,z index=2] {TPTC.dat};
\addlegendentry{proposto}

\addplot3[%
surf,
draw = black,
line width = 0.05pt,
%shader= flat corner,
colormap name=berg,
fill opacity = 0.5,
z buffer=auto,
unbounded coords=jump,
mesh/rows=11]
table[x index=0,y index=1,z index=3] {TPTC.dat};
\addlegendentry{\textit{Bergeron}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I mcould very well be wrong, but as far as I know, pgf-plots has not yet a true 3D engine. That's why the surfaces that should be hidden are not. Asymptote and, to some extent, pstricks do have 3D engines, but I have no idea how data plots work there.

Comment: I am still confident that there are some tricky details that can be implemented in my code and solve the problem.

Comment: Well, if you really want people to look into this, you need to make your code compilable. At present, the data files are missing. The perhaps most convenient way of providing them is to wrap them between `\begin{filecontents}{TPTC.dat}` and `\end{filecontents}`. I am also surprised to see that you're plotting the *same* data twice. Why is that?

Comment: z ordering is not done by default. So that's far from trivial

Comment: Have you considered using the image from Matlab in pgfplots with `\addplot3 graphics`? See *Support for External Three-Dimensional Graphics* in the `pgfplots` manual, p.66 to p.73.

Comment: marmot, I´m not plotting the same data twice. The indexes of z axis are different for each addplot3. I provided the TPTC.dat data in the code.